# How can I effect 'known_hosts' vs self-certified servers for my app's SSL usage?

Tags: java, android, ssl, keystore

Oh wise and noble Oracle,

I'm adding SSL to a TCP client I've written on my Android phone. I can
successfully connect to servers with properly signed certificates, and I can
connect to self-certifying hosts by cooking up a TrustManager implementation
that always thinks everything is fine.

I now have a decorator TrustManager capturing the certificates (before
delegating to its decoratee) for self-certifying hosts and presenting them for
my breathless perusal, but what I can't work out is how to implement ssh's 
behaviour of warning that a host is unknown and offering to remember it for
next time - and doing so.

I presumed all I needed was to store the public key - as ssh does with 
known_hosts - and re-represent it, but with this code and 'sslTrust' holding
the public key:

```
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
    TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(null, null); // initialise!
ks.setKeyEntry("dbentry", Base64.decode(sslTrust, Base64.NO_WRAP), null);
tmf.init(ks);
tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();
ss.stm = new SnoopyTrustManager((X509TrustManager) tms[0]);
// ...
SLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { ss.stm } , null);
ss.factory = context.getSocketFactory();
// ...
SocketFactory factory = ss.getFactory();
mSocket = factory.createSocket(host, port);
```

attempting to establish a connection results in

```
SSLHandshakeException: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: trustAnchors.isEmpty()
```

which is fair enough: I don't know how to cook things up from the certificate 
offered by the remote server. I'm also fairly sure this isn't how I tell a
TrustManager about a remote server's public key anyway.

Since the site is self-certifying, I imagine could probably just verify that
the public keys match in a trivial TrustManager, but I'd like to understand
how this 'should' be done - adding a CA on a per-connection basis, since
I won't trust that CA for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your own trust store on pre-ICS version, and add the serer's certificates to it on first error. Subsequent connections will load it from the trust store and thus trust the remote certificate. This is not a complete solution, but here's one way to do it (code on Github), along with some discussion:

http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html